# CiviCRM 4.7.4 breaks Ajax image upload

Tags: drupal, 4.7, ajax

On Drupal 7.43 (fresh install) / CiviCRM 4.7.8 (same issue on 4.7.4)

After enabling the CiviCRM module the ajax upload of a custom image field added to drupal user accounts stopped working.

Additionally the ajax call fails also when trying to remove previously uploaded images.

The debug URL shows the generic error:
"An unrecoverable error occurred. The uploaded file likely exceeded the maximum file size (80 MB) that this server supports"

Is this a known bug? Any way to resolve it?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

List of enabled Drupal modules:

CiviCRM  CiviCRM (civicrm)                      7.x-4.7.8
 CiviCRM  CiviCRM Theme (civicrmtheme)           7.x-4.7.8
 Core     Block (block)                          7.43
 Core     Color (color)                          7.43
 Core     Comment (comment)                      7.43
 Core     Contextual links (contextual)          7.43
 Core     Dashboard (dashboard)                  7.43
 Core     Database logging (dblog)               7.43
 Core     Field (field)                          7.43
 Core     Field SQL storage (field_sql_storage)  7.43
 Core     Field UI (field_ui)                    7.43
 Core     File (file)                            7.43
 Core     Filter (filter)                        7.43
 Core     Help (help)                            7.43
 Core     Image (image)                          7.43
 Core     List (list)                            7.43
 Core     Menu (menu)                            7.43
 Core     Node (node)                            7.43
 Core     Number (number)                        7.43
 Core     Options (options)                      7.43
 Core     Path (path)                            7.43
 Core     RDF (rdf)                              7.43
 Core     Search (search)                        7.43
 Core     Shortcut (shortcut)                    7.43
 Core     System (system)                        7.43
 Core     Taxonomy (taxonomy)                    7.43
 Core     Text (text)                            7.43
 Core     Toolbar (toolbar)                      7.43
 Core     Update manager (update)                7.43
 Core     User (user)                            7.43

Comment: Solved by commenting lines 881 and 911 on civicm.module `$formValues['no_cache'] = TRUE;` although it's a workaround, would be great to see that fixed. Related to this issue https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16513

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this was a regression caused by https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16513. Further information on the ticket.